# Can CUDA branch divergence help me in this case?

Tags: cuda

This is little more than a thought experiment right now, but I want to check my understanding of the CUDA execution model. Consider the following case:

- I am running on a GPU with poor double-precision performance (a non-Tesla card).
- I have a kernel that needs to calculate a value using double precision. That value is a constant for the rest of the runtime of the kernel, *and* it is also constant across a warp.

Is something like the following pseudocode advantageous?

```
// value that we use later in the kernel; this is constant across all threads
// in a warp
int constant_value;
// check to see if this is the first thread in a warp
enum { warp_size = 32 };
if (!(threadIdx.x & (warp_size - 1))
{
    // only do the double-precision math in one thread
    constant_value = (int) round(double_precision_calculation());
}
// broadcast constant_value to all threads in the warp
constant_value = __shfl(v, 0);
// go on to use constant_value as needed later in the kernel
```

The reason why I considered doing this is my (possibly wrong) understanding of how double-precision resources are made available on each multiprocessor. From what I understand, there are simply 1/32 as many double-precision ALUs as single-precision ones on recent Geforce cards. Does this mean that if the other threads in a warp diverge, I can work around this lack of resources, and still get decent performance, as long as the double-precision values that I want can be broadcast to all threads in a warp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that if the other threads in a warp diverge, I can work around this lack of resources, and still get decent performance, as long as the double-precision values that I want can be broadcast to all threads in a warp?

No, you can't.

An instruction issue *always* occurs at the warp level, even in a warp-diverged scenario.  Since it is issued at the warp level, it will require/use/schedule enough execution resources for the warp, even for inactive threads.

Therefore a computation done on only one thread will still use the same resources/scheduling slot as a computation done on all 32 threads in the warp.

For example, a floating point multiply will require 32 instances of usage of a floating point ALU.  The exact scheduling of this will vary based on the specific GPU, but you cannot reduce the 32 instance usage to a lower number through warp divergence or any other mechanism.

Based on a question in the comments, here's a worked example on CUDA 7.5, Fedora 20, GT640 (GK208 - has 1/24 ratio of DP to SP units):

```
$ cat t1241.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define USECPSEC 1000000ULL

unsigned long long dtime_usec(unsigned long long start){

  timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
  return ((tv.tv_sec*USECPSEC)+tv.tv_usec)-start;
}

const int nTPB = 32;
const int nBLK = 1;
const int rows = 1048576;
const int nSD = 128;

typedef double mytype;
template <bool use_warp>
__global__ void mpy_k(const mytype * in, mytype * out){
  __shared__ mytype sdata[nTPB*nSD];
  int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  mytype accum = in[idx];
#pragma unroll 128
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    if (use_warp)
      accum += accum*sdata[threadIdx.x+(i&(nSD-1))*nTPB];
    else
      if (threadIdx.x == 0)
        accum += accum*sdata[threadIdx.x+(i&(nSD-1))*nTPB];
  out[idx] = accum;
}

int main(){
  mytype *din, *dout;
  cudaMalloc(&din, nTPB*nBLK*rows*sizeof(mytype));
  cudaMalloc(&dout, nTPB*nBLK*sizeof(mytype));
  cudaMemset(din, 0, nTPB*nBLK*rows*sizeof(mytype));
  cudaMemset(dout, 0, nTPB*nBLK*sizeof(mytype));
  mpy_k<true><<<nBLK, nTPB>>>(din, dout); // warm-up
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  unsigned long long dt = dtime_usec(0);
  mpy_k<true><<<nBLK, nTPB>>>(din, dout);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dt = dtime_usec(dt);
  printf("full warp elapsed time: %f\n", dt/(float)USECPSEC);
  mpy_k<false><<<nBLK, nTPB>>>(din, dout); //warm up
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dt = dtime_usec(0);
  mpy_k<false><<<nBLK, nTPB>>>(din, dout);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dt = dtime_usec(dt);
  printf("one thread elapsed time: %f\n", dt/(float)USECPSEC);
  cudaError_t res = cudaGetLastError();
  if (res != cudaSuccess) printf("CUDA runtime failure %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(res));
  return 0;
}

$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t1241 t1241.cu
$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="1" ./t1241
full warp elapsed time: 0.034346
one thread elapsed time: 0.049174
$
```

It is not faster to use just one thread in the warp for a floating-point multiply

Comment: Thanks for the authoritative answer. No free lunch here!

Comment: What about if I had a calculation that was constant at the block level? Could I save any time by making the calculations happen in one warp only, then share the result in shared memory?

Comment: Possibly, yes.  When divergence occurs at warp boundaries, there is no cost to the divergence.  Stated another way, if an entire warp follows a code path for which no instructions of a particular type are executed (e.g. floating point multiply) then that warp will not issue any instructions of that type at that point, and no resources of that type will be used.  The warp doing the calculations could in fact perform 32 "different" calculations (e.g. a floating point multiply with 32 different sets of operands) as long as there is no divergence, and provide those results to the rest of the block

Comment: Has anyone ever timed this? I don't have a card at hand that cripples double precision throughput to 1/24th. If I had, it seems worthwhile/interesting to check whether the multi-cycle instructions are implemented via instruction replay. I could imagine this using the same silicon that also handles e.g. shared memory bank conflicts, for which the number of cycles does depend on active threads (and addresses requested).

Comment: Yes, I've timed it.  I've updated my answer with a worked example.  If you disagree with my sample or the conclusion, feel free to provide your own worked example that demonstrates another conclusion.

Comment: Thanks Robert for going to the lengths of testing this! I would have thought that a compute-bound code would be better suited for the test than a memory-bound one, but as I said I don't have the hardware at hand to test myself.

Comment: I've updated the code to a non memory bound code.  The one thread case is not faster.